# How to display powerpoint in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, powerpoint

I'm looking for a way for users to upload a powerpoint file to my site (not a third party presentation site unless its free and they have a upload api) and then I would display the presentation in the browser. Is there a rails gem that can handle this or easily covert the powerpoint presentation into images?

Comment: So basically you want for someone to have written all of this functionality for you, and you just want to call their APIs and boom there's your product?

Comment: I said if there was something that coverts powerpoint slides into images i would handle the rest.

Comment: If i was you i will use https://docs.google.com/viewer in embedded mode (in iframe maybe), the result will be better than all gems you can found. OpenOffice and LibreOffice are 2 fat applications and cannot display correctly a power point so a simple gem in ruby, i don't think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the above with the [Scribd API](http://www.scribd.com/developers/platform):

> The Scribd API is a REST-like API with methods for uploading, converting, viewing, deleting, and searching documents.